# Should I grind the edge or the backbevel first when sharpening my knife?

Tags: gear-care, knives, knife-sharpening

I'm using a [Spyderco Tri-angle sharpmaker](http://www.spyderco.com/catalog/details.php?product=77) to sharpen both a drop-point fixed blade and a folding tanto blade. It has 2 settings:

1. 2 20 degree sides for a 40 degree working edge
2. 2 15 degree sides for a 30 degree back bevel

Like it says in the title, is there a particular order I should be grinding the knife?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You sharpen the secondary / backbevel (the 15 degrees) when you do not get that hair-popping sharpness form the 20 degree angle.

Or you use the 15 degrees to get a knife with a thick bevel to razor-sharpness and then use the 20 degrees afterwards.

I think the CD that comes with the sharpmaker has some more hints.
A visual for your target bevel from spyderco:
http://www.spyderco.com/edge-u-cation/index.php?item=20